# Rotate ImageButton onCreate without Animation

Tags: android, rotation, imagebutton, oncreate

Is it possible to rotate an ImageButton using the onCreate() function? Or do you have to use an Animation which starts onCreate()?  Because with an Animation i can see a little "flick" on Activity start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `ViewCompat.setRotation(buttonInstance, rotationAngle);`. From the documentation

> Sets the degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `onDraw()` method using a custom class that extends `ImageButton` (which I'm sure you have).

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Rotate a Bitmap
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setRotate(angle, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
        /*
         * OR
        **/
        // Rotate the canvas
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(-angle);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Choose one or the other solution, not both together ;)

**EDIT**

After some quick reflection, that could also work (not tested):

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.rotate(-angle);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
```